# CKEditor 5 css not working (Blockquote and Code )

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I'm using code and blockquote in CKEditor 5 and when I render the post the page is not grayed out it just writes as if it were normal post

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlPks.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Znt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uILng.png)

I deleted and reinstalled CKEditor 5, it still happens like this and saves it to the database section as it should.

**Database View**

<blockquote><h2>I'm trying blockquote</h2></blockquote><pre><code class="language-plaintext">#CodeExample <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pe-5 "> <mat-label>Başlık</mat-label> <input matInput [formControl]="title" required> <mat-error *ngIf="title.invalid">{{getErrorMessagetitle()}}</mat-error> </mat-form-field></code></pre><p> </p>

Comment: Can you give more information about the setup of CKEditor in your project? If it's an Angular one, did you use a wrapper like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ckeditor ?